# Java - How to reverse and split a number by digit into an array?

Tags: java

I'm learning java coming from a ruby background and self-teaching.

I am doing a problem that wants a number reversed and listed into an array by digit.

Ex 1234 -> [4,3,2,1]

In ruby I did this easily -

```
def digitize(n)
  n.to_s.reverse.split("").map(&:to_i)
end
```

In java, my code is not working, because clearly, I am doing something wrong.

```
public class Kata {
  public static int[] digitize(long n) {

  String s = String.valueOf(n);
  String r = reverse(s, s.length()-1);
  String[] array = r.split("");
  Float[] floats = Arrays.stream(array).map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);
  }

  return floats;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this with built-in methods like ruby? I tried doing everything separately. First variable **s**, I wanted to convert the number to a string. Second variable **r**, reversing that string. Third variable **array**, splitting the variable r into digits. **Floats** at the end was to convert the array of strings to digits.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: I would use a StringBuilder.reverse because I am lazy

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Kata {
  public static int[] digitize(long n) {
    String numStr = String.valueOf(n);
    int digits[] = new int[numStr.length()];
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = numStr.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      digits[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(numStr.charAt(counter++)));
    }

    return digits;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns `Float[]` instead of `int[]`. Try this:

```
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(array).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
return ints;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JDK:

```
int[] reversedDigits = Arrays.stream(new StringBuilder().append(n).reverse().toString().split("(?<=.)")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Not as terse as ruby. A little embarrassing actually, but 1 line nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect a `List` and then `reverse` it with `Collections.reverse(List)` and then convert that to an `int[]`. Something like,

```
public static int[] digitize(long n) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    List<Integer> al = s.chars().map(ch -> Character.digit(ch, 10))
            .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.reverse(al);
    return al.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

**or** exploit the `String.length()` to build the array directly like

```
public static int[] digitize(long n) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    int[] out = new int[s.length()];
    IntStream.range(0, s.length()).forEach( //
            i -> out[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1), 10));
    return out;
}
```

**or** combine that with a `map` for the even shorter

```
public static int[] digitize(long n) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    return IntStream.range(0, s.length()) //
            .map(i -> Character.digit(s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1), 10)).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class Kata {
  public static float[] digitize(long n) {

  int[] ints= new StringBuffer(n.toString()).reverse().toString().split("(?!^)").mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();;

  return ints;
}
```